# What is the limiting distribution of $Y_n = \sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n-1)$ as $n \to \infty$?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, convergence, method-of-moments

Let $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ be independently and identically distributed with pdf $f(x)=e^{-x}, 0 < x < \infty$. Let $Y_n = \sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n-1)$.

What is the limiting distribution of $Y_n$ as $n \to \infty$?

My work:

I decided to try an mgf approach. Clearly, $X_1,\cdots,X_n \sim Exp(1)$, so $M_{X_i}(t)=\frac{1}{1-t}, t < 1$. After a bit of work, I found that

$M_{Y_n}(t)=[e^{t/\sqrt{n}}(1-\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}})]^{-n}, t < \sqrt{n}$. This does not appear to resemble a known distribution's mgf. Should I change my approach?

**Updated:**

I think I'm supposed to solve the problem using an mfg method. Now I am getting this:

$M_{y_n}(t)=[[1 + \frac{t}{\sqrt{n}} + (\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}})^2\cdot1/2! + \cdots]-[\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}} +(\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}})^2+(\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}})^3\cdot 1/3!+\cdots]]^{-n}$, which resembles some work that we have done in class, but I am not too sure how I can evaluate this.

**Additional Update:**

Due to Glen_b's comment, I attempted using CLT. Here is my updated "updated work."

Since $X_i \sim Exp(1), i=1,\cdots,n$, then $E(X_i)=1, Var(X_i)=1$. So,

$\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n-1) \to N(0,1)$ in distribution by Central Limit Theorem, which matches the answers provided below.

Comment: Hint: $\bar{X}_n$ has a Gamma distribution

Comment: @StijnDeVuyst So, I get than $Y_n$ is a location-scale Gamma, where the mgf of a $Gamma(\alpha, \beta) =[1-\beta t]^{-\alpha}$. However, I do not know how to evaluate $Y_n$ as $n \to \infty$ given this information.

Comment: @StijnDeVuyst I updated the post with new work.

Comment: If you're using the mgf approach (NB I have not checked your mgf is correct), what happens to the function in the limit as $n\to \infty$?

Comment: Are you allowed to invoke the Central Limit Theorem?  (Even if not, it tells you immediately what the limiting distribution is, which can guide your demonstration.)

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica Since I do not know how to further expand $M_{Y_n}(t)$, I cannot successfully evaluate the mgf as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @whuber I believe I could. How would that be used to find the limiting distribution, though?

Comment: @edison (i) regarding to your discussion with whuber -- what does the CLT say? (ii) On the other hand if (as I had previously assumed) you can't invoke the CLT, you have already expanded $M$ (though as I say I am not checking your work), what you'd need next is to use facts about limits.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica This makes sense- thank you for your help. I assumed that I couldn't use CLT because $Y_n$ would be incredibly hard to manipulate in order to employ CLT.

Comment: No, it's incredibly easy to deal with. What's $\mu_Y$? What's $\sigma_Y$? Write down a standardized $\bar{Y}$ ...

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica I added an updated answer using CLT. Thank you for pointing out its ease. I was over-thinking it.

Comment: You can post it as an answer, since it answers your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your updated version, you will get $\left[1 - \frac{t^2/2}{n} +o(\frac{1}{n})\right]^{-n} = \left[1 + \frac{t^2/2}{n} +o(\frac{1}{n})\right]^{n}$

and the limit of that is $e^{t^2/2}$, which is the moment generating function of a standard normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $1$, much as you might expect from the central limit theorem

Comment: What is $o(\frac{1}{n})$? Sorry, I am not familiar with this notation. Additionally, how do you get that equality?

Comment: @Edison This is [Little o notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation) and here means means that the remainder when divided by $\frac1n$ tends to $0$ as $n$ increases so eventually very much smaller in magnitude than $\frac1n$ or $\frac{t^2/2}{n}$.  The equality is similar to saying $\frac{1}{1-x} = 1+x +\cdots$ but here we have $\frac{t^2/2}{n}$ rather than $x$

Comment: Thank you for linking the Wikipedia article- that was very helpful. I get that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n = e^x$, but how come we can neglect $o(\frac{1}{n})$? Also, how did you know to keep the $-\frac{t^2/n}{n}$ term out of $o(\frac{1}{n})$?